# Coq + Emacs? ``Check`` can't see what is defined in the source file

Tags: emacs, coq

So I am playing with `Coq` using `Emacs` as the IDE. Both `proof-general` and `company-coq` are installed and load correctly.

Then I open dummy `whatever_name.v` file and define recursive function using the `Fixpoint` keyword.

Then I run `coq-Check` on it and get:

> > Check addnm .
>
> Error: The reference addnm was not found in the current environment.

However, for example, `Inductive unit : Set := tt.` works perfectly well.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the impression you did not ask Coq to *read* the `addnm` definition. Try pressing `C-c C-n` on your Coq buffer. This should instruct Proof General to send in the next command to Coq for processing. You should see your buffer progressively turning a different color as the commands are sent. Once the definition of `addnm` is highlighted, you should be able to check it (`C-c C-a C-c`).

(The reason `unit` still works is that its definition is automatically loaded when you start Coq in Emacs.)

Comment: You saved my day, thanks. I didn't know that `unit` does exist.